# Changing The Textarea Resize Icon With CSS3

Tags: css

Is there anyway of changing the textarea's re-size icon with CSS?

I'd like to change it to something cleaner, like a simple arrow.

Is this in anyway possible? Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```css
 div {
   border: 1px solid;
   padding: 10px;
   width: 200px;
   resize: both;
   overflow: auto;
 }
```

```html
<div>Hello World!!!</div>
```

Try this ...